# Multiple scatter plots on one plot

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I am having two audio files and I am taking their 1D convolution. The output has 3 points for each audio file. I wanted to plot the outputs of both the files on the scatter plot but I am able to plot just the last output. Can anybody please help me to plot both the outputs?

```
path = 'C:/Users/....'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.wav')):
    sample_rate,audio = wavfile.read(filename)
    x = audio
    z = x.reshape(1,audio.shape[0],1)
    z = tf.constant(z, dtype=tf.float32)
    print(x.shape)
    print(audio.shape[0])
    y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 44095, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,audio.shape[0],1))(z)
    y=y.numpy()

    print(y)
    aa=y.reshape(-1)
    
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(np.arange(3), aa, color = 'crimson')
plt.show()
```

The plot that I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: In your code you are plotting a `np.arange` rather than the contents of your files, is this intended?

Comment: @Caridorc I am using (np.arange(3), aa) as in aa there are three points. This is my understanding. I didn't came across a better way to do it.

Comment: Ah yes of course sorry, did you try moving `fig = plt.figure()` outside of the loop?

Comment: @Caridorc Yes, still gives me the same result.

Comment: Try also moving `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` outside the loop

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: ok, now it is weird, try printing the filename to make sure that the code finds and iterates over both files, also print the `aa` variable to see if the problem is generating it or plotting it

Comment: C:/Users/.....\tv1.wav
[2348.0747 2868.0022 2910.5315]
C:/Users/....\tv2.wav
[1452.976  2294.6594 2111.9297]

This is what I am getting. Both the filename as well as different values of aa.

Comment: ok I got an idea, try setting xlimit and ylimit and zlimit manually to include the range of both files

Comment: Maybe both are plotted but you only see one because the graph limit is too small, do this with fig and ax defined outside the loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251098/discussion-between-a-gehani-and-caridorc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need 3d for your case, as you have index + feature, so you only need 2 dimensions for each point, you can use the default 2d plotting context and use:

```
    # in the loop
    plt.scatter(np.arange(3), aa, color = 'crimson')
# outside the loop
plt.show()
```